# Help me understand Probability Question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The probability that a bulb is working is 0.7. what is the probability that out of 6 bulbs picked: only one is working; all of them are working; at least half of them are working.

Comment: Looking at your work so far I can spot your error:  *You haven't shown any work so far.*  It helps if you include your efforts, or at leasts thoughts, about attempting to solve the problem.  Then people can see what you understand, and where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

(a) Only of them is working: in that case choose the bulb that is working in 6 ways (as there are six bulbs), then probability is $6*(0.3)^5*(0.7)$ since all bulb are work independently (you have to assume this, otherwisse the question cannot be solved with given information), and probability of a bulb not working is $1-0.7=0.3$.

(b)For all of them to work, probability is obviously $(0.7)^6$

(c)For half of them to work at least: there are four cases, either 3 work, or 4 work, or 5 work, or 6 bulbs work. The probabilities are $^6C_3*(0.3)^3*(0.7)^3$, $^6C_4*(0.3)^2*(0.7)^4$, $^6C_5*(0.3)^1*(0.7)^5$, $^6C_6*(0.3)^0*(0.7)^6=(0.7)^6$ respectively. So, the answer is $^6C_3*(0.3)^3*(0.7)^3+^6C_4*(0.3)^2*(0.7)^4+^6C_5*(0.3)^1*(0.7)^5+(0.7)^6$